# AWS IoT - how to specify the certificate path (Swagger + NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, swagger, iot

I am working with AWS IoT, and try to publish a topic on AWS IoT.

What I have done:

- Register a thing and setup policies (download 4 certificate files) from AWS IoT
- install sdk with npm (https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js)
- Copy all certificate files (4 files) to a folder "cert", same level with app.js
- In Swagger controllers, create a file js and copy sample code as link above.
- In file js, update code as below

  var device = awsIot.device({
  keyPath: 'cert/xxxxxx-private.pem.key',
  certPath: 'cert/xxxxxx-certificate.pem.crt',
  caPath: 'cert/rootCA.pem',
  clientId: 'TestIoT',
  host: 'xxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com'
  });

What error I received :

> Invalid "keyPath" option supplied.
>       at module.exports (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/common/lib/tls-reader.js:92:13)
>       at new DeviceClient (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/device/index.js:416:7)
>       at Object.DeviceClient [as device] (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/device/index.js:201:14)

As I understand, the path is not specified correctly. Please give me some advices how to specify the path correctly.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try relative paths:

```
'./cert/xxxxxx-private.pem.key'
```

It is the same path but adding "./" at the start.